# How does Cloud Data Fusion decide which project network to use for the dataproc resources?

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I have a project with 4 VPC networks. I created a  GCDF instance, I had expected that the "default" network would be picked but I see that another one was picked, (the first one alphabetically). Is this the algorithm, the alphabetic order of names?

Is there a way to specify the network to be used, that would be very useful since I would like to isolate the network where those VMs run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your observation is correct. Current implementation selects network alphabetically. To use specific network, there are multiple options:

1. Create a dataproc compute profile that uses default or any other VPC network you have already created.
2. Use `system.profile.properties.network=default` as system preference.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I already discovered and used the compute profile and works very well.